# Which is faster: Empty Function Call or If Statements?

Tags: c, performance

I was implementing a circular buffer to store fixed-sized data structures like a queue. This circular buffer is initialized with three parameters:-

```
/*
 * Initialize the ring buffer.
 * @capacity Max capacity of ring buffer.
 * @item_size Fixed size of item that will be put in this circular buffer.
 * @item_cleaner Clean callback, NULL if cleanup not required.
 */
ringbuf*
ringbuf_create(size_t capacity, size_t item_size, clean_up_cb item_cleaner)
```

My circular buffer is always in `wrapping` mode which means that last item is always replaced when new item is put in full circular buffer. Since, dynamically allocated objects can also be put into this buffer, therefore, circular buffer keeps reference a clean-up callback function to free up the items when they are replaced or deleted. But at the same time, this call back function can also be `NULL` (when no clean up is required). Everywhere in my code, I've statements like these:-

```
if(buffer->callback != NULL)
   buffer->callback(item);
```

Now, to prevent these `if` statement, I put empty stub function when user does not provide any call back function. This prevent me to check every time if callback function is `NULL` or not.

Using this approach, my code looks neat to me. But I'm not sure, which one of them is faster? On assembly level, how does `empty function call` and `if statement` relate in terms of speed? Are they equivalent?

Comment: How about you just measure it? Alternatively, if performance is that vital and the code is executed that frequently (unlikely, do you have proof that it matters?) you could use the preprocessor to generate a version that has no callback.

Comment: Try it. Also remember that on most processors the performance of `if` depends on how predictable it is which side is chosen (so when you're trying it, make the test do something realistic). And if you're going to ask performance questions, include the platform you're targeting - it's just as important as the code itself.

Comment: Depends. Compiler? Optimization level?

Comment: It depends on the compiler, compiler settings, target architecture, the ABI and the actual processor. So a real answer requires this data. I your case, I would go with the neater code. It might be faster or slower, but not much either way.

Comment: Don't feel bad if you attract a lecture about being penny-wise pound-foolish :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty stub function is actually two JMP operations and allot of PUSH/POP operations on the CPU. An IF is usually a single COMP operation which is much cheaper than any JMP+PUSHS+POPS.

If your 'IF's usually return false/true then I won't worry about it as the CPU optimizes IFs in a very good way by predicting the result as long as the IFs are "predictable" (usually returns true or false or has some pattern of true/false)

I would go with the IFs.

Comment: Actually, a conditional jump instruction is produced even in the case of `if`. That is what an `if` really is: A conditional jump.

Comment: Proof: http://pastebin.com/ZBPuVF5P when compiled with `gcc -O3 -S` has a `je` instruction in the assembler code output.

Comment: You are correct and you are wrong. An if is actually a conditional jump but the optimization is not in the assembly but in the CPU. The CPU tracks all conditional jumps in a branch prediction tables and optimizes the execution. Read more at http://igoro.com/archive/fast-and-slow-if-statements-branch-prediction-in-modern-processors/

Comment: Where am I wrong? Where did I say anything about 'optimization'? I said: An `if` produces a conditional jump. It is pretty clear that the conditional jump is subject to branch prediction by the CPU. I never said it is not.

Comment: On the other hand, in its current version, *your answer* essentially says: 'An `if` produces a single COMP which is much cheaper than any JMP+PUSHS+POPS'. This, is wrong. An `if` does not produce a single COMP. It produces a conditional jump also, which may or may not pan out well.

Comment: To be clear: My comment was *not* about who optimizes the conditional jump. It was merely about the fact that an `if` leads to code generation which *includes* a conditional jump, and not just a comparison operation. I am not even saying that an `if` is *not* the better option.

Comment: An *inlined* empty function call would likely be incredibly fast!

Comment: @BoPersson - Yes. However, it cannot be inlined if the function being called is not known at compile time. Also, like @Gilad says, an `if` with a predictable result is also pretty fast.

Answer (score 5):

Without worrying about speed, I'd probably just code:

```
 if (buffer->callback) buffer->callback(item);
```

simply because it's clear and idiomatic as it is. And it'll certainly be no slower than a null function call.